# creating html to call Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps

I inherited some code that worked with Bing Maps v6 so I'm now trying to reproduce functionality in v8. I did the following as an initial attempt, but even this doesn't seem to work. (I've tried to follow https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34568.bing-maps-v6-3-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx along with various other bits I've found online, but I'm coming into this with no knowledge at all of Bing maps, so I've erred in apparently significant ways since this gets no results. Happy for all guidance.

I've omitted our Bing key below, but other than that, this is the code I attempted to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title here</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    </head>
    <body>         
        <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
                var map;
                function loadMap() {
                    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                        credentials: 'BingKeyOmittedHereForSecurityPurposes'
                    });
                    map.Geocode('Jericho, VT', GeocodeCallback);
                }
                function GeocodeCallback(layer, results, places, hasMore, veErrorMessage) {
                // no idea what should be here
                }            
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' 
        src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=loadMap' async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'll be adding Pins and possible directions once I get this working, but figured I should get the basics working before getting fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map doesn't have a geocode function, instead you have to use the search module. Bing Maps V7 and above break out additional functionalities using modules. This makes for a much lighter page load compared to V6 which had every possible feature crammed into a single downloaded file.

In any case here is a sample of how to geocode in V8. https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsV8CodeSamples/blob/master/Samples/Search/Geocode.html

Here are some resources to help you with your migration:

[Bing Maps V8 code samples](http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net)

[Bing Maps V6.3 to V8 Migration Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34568.bing-maps-v6-3-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx)